# React tutorial function calculateWinner(squares) don't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem understand this code in the react tutorial page https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#declaring-a-winner

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This particular line

```
if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
```

I don't understand why it can't be

```
if (squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
```

What benefits are of having the extra squares[a] in the original code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the `squares[a]` in the begin of `if` condition, you can get the js error if `squares[a]` is not defined.

For simple, we have the condition like this:

```
if (a && a === b && a === c) {
```

it will check the `a` variable first, if it not defined, the after will not execute.

Comment: It won`t throw an error in this case, it will be just "undefined". For Example, var a = {} and a["foo"] will be undefined. Hence, in above case it will check for (undefined === sqaures[b]) etc. If sqaures is not defined then only it will throw error that "cannot read property a of undefined".

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari Thank you. You are right. In my answer, you will get an error if it is not defined. So if you define it with any value, it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is checked if squares[a] is not null, undefined, 0, empty string '' and false, so that further checks of squares[a] would be possible. If squares[a] is null or undefined or false or 0 then the condition would return false and further checks won't be done due to "&&" condtion operator.