# I'm trying to make sense of the React TicTacToe tutorial. How does their calculateWinner helper function operate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all this is not a dupe of [React tutorial function calculateWinner(squares) don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977819/react-tutorial-function-calculatewinnersquares-dont-understand).

Looking at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#declaring-a-winner:

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];


  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    const[a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]){
      return squares[a];
    }

  }
  return null;
}
```

What does `const[a, b, c] = lines[i];` do? What are squares[a],squares[b] and squares[c]? I understand that the lines array contains all of the combinations of square positions that result in a win, but I can't understand how they are being defined and compared and the tutorial really doesn't offer any explanation, just "Here's a helper function that'll make it all work."

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
const[a, b, c] = lines[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
const a = lines[i][0];
const b = lines[i][1];
const c = lines[i][2];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Tic-tac-toe code
https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/LyyXgK?editors=0010

`squares` are the `slice` of `squares` from the grid

Answer (score 0):

`lines[i]` refers to one of eight combinations of three values (`[0, 1, 2]`, `[3, 4, 5]`, etc.). `const[a, b, c] = lines[i];` assigns those three values to the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. This makes the condition in the following `if` statement a lot more concise, as those three variables are used as indices to the `squares` array.